# Can't make a fraction

Tags: fractions

I had been tried for a long time, but it had worked, I have this code, hope you can help me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{pmatrix} 
m\\
n
\end{pmatrix} = {\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry I missed the problem, that is that the "m!" inside the fraction inside {} of \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!} is outside the fraction

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can always edit your own question to add additional information. I edited your question to format your source as an actual code block (button `{}`).

Comment: The `m!` is only a problem in the output. Have you checked the `.log`. It complains about `Missing $ inserted`? That means that you have used macros (`\frac`) or environments (`pmatrix`) that are only allowed in “math mode”. You must enter math mode to use those correctly. Enclose the whole formula for example in an `equation` environment. The fact that everything else except `m!` is typeset correct is pure luck as (La)TeX itself tries to determine where you had to use math mode.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the `\frac` command in math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
In display style
\[
  \begin{pmatrix} m \\ n \end{pmatrix} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}
\]
or inline math mode $\begin{pmatrix} m \\ n \end{pmatrix} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$.
\end{document}
```

If you're trying to write a binomial expression, it's better to use `\binom{m}{n}`. It formats better in both of the math styles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
In display style
\[
  \binom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}
\]
or inline math mode $\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$.
\end{document}
```